# Interaction of structs with object attributes and std::vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I have encountered this problem and am wondering what its cause is.

My code is as follows:

```
struct node{
  bool leaf;
  std::string label;
};

//in main
std::vector<node> graph;
graph.reserve(5);
```

Now, if i try to assign
    `graph[3].leaf = true;`,
everything works out.

However, if i try to do the same with an object type, like
    `graphA[i].label = "01";`,
I get a segmentation fault.

If i change the code to

```
struct node{
  bool leaf;
  std::string * label;
};
```

And allocate the memory for the string in every instance of `node` in the vector, I can now assign a value to `graphA[i]->label` without a problem.

Why is this? Any responses will be appreciated.

Comment: `graph.reserve(5);` => `graph.resize(5);` should fix it. You don't need a pointer and `new`.

Comment: try `graph.at(3)` to get a nicer error message

Comment: `reserve` just reserves, your vector still has zero elements

Comment: @tobi303: If the exception leaves `main`, there may not be a nice error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, if i try to assign `graph[3].leaf = true;`, everything works out.

It's important to stress that this is a mere coincidence. Nothing works out - you have **undefined behaviour** because you access `graph[3]` when `graph` is empty. It would be much better if the program crashed right away, so that you notice something is wrong.

`graph` is empty because you confused `std::vector`'s `reserve` and `resize` member functions. You don't set the vector's element count to 5, you just ask it to prepare its internally held memory for at least 5 elements in the future. `std::vector` is even allowed to ignore this request.

When you do `graphA[i].label = "01";`, you also have undefined behaviour, of course.

So why do the first version and the pointer "fix" (which also invokes undefined behaviour) seem to work fine while the other one crashes? C++ as a programming language does not distinguish between different kinds of undefined behaviour. **Anything can happen**; you may as well experience situations in which the first crashes and the second one "works out". Such is the nature of undefined behaviour.

What *probably* happens here in practice is that in the `bool` and `std::string*` case, you are coincidentally writing to a memory location your program is allowed to write to, because you are just dealing with a single `bool` or with a single pointer. In the `std::string` version, with all of `std::string`'s automatic dynamic memory management happening behind the scenes, more places in memory are involved and so it happens that you hit a forbidden one.

But that's just a very speculative theory. If you really want to know for sure, debug the code and step into each individual operation. But remember that undefined behaviour is always undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

> Now, if i try to assign `graph[3].leaf = true;`

You're invoking undefined behavior.

`graph` has no element at index 3. In fact, it has no elements at all. You only *`reserve`d memory* for the vector, but didn't add any elements to it.

You can add 5 default-constructed elements using `resize`:

```
graph.resize(5);
```